# CHDIR not changing directory everytime?

Tags: php, css

i have a wepsite with an included Header & Searchbar.

Because the files are included i have to try to explicitly set the directory to compensate for the Working Directory Changes caused by different pages using the Include files.

This has however caused a few errors that i am struggling to deal with.

I have tried CHDIR & `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to set the Dir to the Curent File Directory.
and allthough CHDIR does indeed set the directory.

For some reason when i try to link href my `CSS` file , the error i receive in console is

1. Not allowed to load local resource: -- `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
   or
2. net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) -- chdir(**DIR**)

instead of the directory changing because of the CHDIR to -> `vbay/InnerElements/TopBanner/css/`

in console the error displays the directory -> `localhost/css/topbannercss.css` - `404`

When i use CHDIR i can Echo Getcwd(); and it returns the correct directory -> `vbay/InnerElements/TopBanner/css/`

however when i use the `CHDIR` and set a variable i get the `404` wrror and the Directory in console has not been changed.. Strange?

So allthought the directory does get changed, it is not used when loading my `CSS` file.

Does anybody know how i can deal with this issue correctly.

So no matter where i use the include files i can set the directory explicitly and the `CSS` will load.

iv been struggling with this matter all weekend and it has alot to do with the Includes and Directories.

here is a little code.

This works fine and the include is loaded However the code within the included file throws the errors and does not load my `CSS`.

//LANDINGPAGE

```
$newdir=(__DIR__ . '');
chdir($newdir);

    $topbanner='../../InnerElements/topbanner/html/topbanner.php';
    
    if (file_exists($topbanner) AND is_readable($topbanner)) {  
        include($topbanner);    
    }
    else{   
        throw new Exception();
       }
```

TOPBANNER (does not load the CSS file) - but correct path

```
chdir(__DIR__ . '');

$topbannercss='../css/topbannercss.css';
                    
        
        if (file_exists($topbannercss) AND is_readable($topbannercss)) {            
            ECHO"
            
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='".$topbannercss."'></link>
        ";
        }
        else{   
            throw new Exception();  
            }
```

instead of the directory changing because of the CHDIR to -> `vbay/InnerElements/TopBanner/css/`

in console the error displays the directory -> `localhost/css/topbannercss.css - 404`

So allthough the `CHDIR` does change the directory. for some reason it is not fulfilled

Can any1 help me out here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`chdir` changes the working directory for the PHP program.

It has absolutely no effect on the URL that the browser asks the server for, or how the server resolves that separate request.

Comment: right, i understand. but the problem i have is setting the directory to fetch the css file from browser as the css file is obviously on my computer (server eventually) and i need to be able to change directorys correctly regardless of Current Working directory to fetch the css file , if i excplicitly add the directory i get this error not allowed to load local resource:. so its a tricky 1 for me. is there any other way of loading CSS. i suppose i could add the css in the PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

O.k

one Current Solution

Rather than loading thee CSS as a Link Href

I have changed it to include the css file with the CSS in STYLE TAGS...

Seems to of worked but i now need to alter the image directories within the css.
and unfortunatly i have the same directory problem. the current working directory is set to the page where the include was initiated and not the included files location, therfore the images in the css are not loaded up.

But is a very cheap way around what could of been done intelligently.